# Show user only those products which he hasn't buyed using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Is there any direct query by which we can show user only those product which the login user has not buyed yet using laravel eloquent functionality

I am new to the laravel relations and eloquent queries

Up-till Now i have tried using the queries like

```
DB::raw('Select * from products 
where products.id not in ( "Select product_id from order_product
left join orders on orders.id = order_product.order_id 
left join users on users.id = orders.user_id 
where users.id='.$user_id.'")');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what have you tried so far? what is your guess at how you would go about it?

Comment: Pseudocode: `Product::whereDoesntHave('user', function($query) { $query->where("id", Auth::id()); });`

Comment: I am new to the laravel eloquent i am stuck with this query but cannot find the simple answer i usually tried with raw queries is there any better solution to it.

Comment: its okay to be new at something :) ... how would you have done this with a raw query? do you have any relations setup on the models for these tables?

Comment: yes i have relationship setup inside the model i have a model for products and users but finding for the best solution to it.

Comment: provide the relationship methods for the models and perhaps someone can provide some guidance in the right direction (you can provide that information by editing your question and adding it there)... though i don't know what you mean by "direct query"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try something like this, it will solve your problem**

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;

Product::where('status', 'active')

  ->whereNotIn('id', function($query) use ($user_id) {

    $query->select('product_id')->from((new OrderProduct)->getTable())

      ->where('user_id', $user_id)->where('status', 'delivered')

        ->pluck('product_id')->toArray();

  });
```

Comment: Why do you make it so complex, when you can just create a relation and use relational queries like `whereHas()` or `whereDoesntHave()`?

Comment: Okay thank you for the suggestion i will surely work on that part for further laravel eloquent questions :)